# Chrome and Safari reading CSS differently?

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

Never thought I'd say this but Google Chrome is being rather annoying.

I'm attempting to have a little gallery on a webpage and on Safari it displays 100% correctly all tight an in shape:

[image: Safari displaying webpage]

Yet when loading the same page on Google Chrome it's very off center.

[image: Chrome Displaying webpage]

However using Google Chrome on my iPhone it all displays nice too.

Here's the section of the CSS sheet for the javascript gallery.

```
#slideshow {list-style:none; color:#fff}
#slideshow span {display:none}
#wrapper {width:725px; margin:50px auto; display:none}
#wrapper * {margin:0; padding:0}
#fullsize {position:relative; width:720px; height:540px; padding:2px; border:1px solid         #ccc; background:#000}
#information {position:absolute; bottom:0; width:720px; height:0; background:#000;   color:#fff; overflow:hidden; z-index:200; opacity:.7; filter:alpha(opacity=70)}
#information h3 {padding:4px 8px 3px; font-size:14px}
#information p {padding:0 8px 8px}
#image {width:720px}
#image img {position:absolute; z-index:25; width:auto}
.imgnav {position:absolute; width:25%; height:306px; cursor:pointer; z-index:150}
#imgprev {left:0; background:url(gallery/images/left.gif) left center no-repeat}
#imgnext {right:0; background:url(gallery/images/right.gif) right center no-repeat}
#imglink {position:absolute; height:306px; width:100%; z-index:100; opacity:.4;   filter:alpha(opacity=40)}
.linkhover {background:url(images/link.gif) center center no-repeat}
#thumbnails {margin-top:15px}
#slideleft {float:left; width:20px; height:81px; background:url(gallery/images/scroll-  left.gif) center center no-repeat; background-color:#222}
#slideleft:hover {background-color:#333}
#slideright {float:right; width:20px; height:81px; background:#222     url(gallery/images/scroll-right.gif) center center no-repeat}
#slideright:hover {background-color:#333}
#slidearea {float:left; position:relative; width:675px; margin-left:5px; height:81px;  overflow:hidden}
#slider {position:absolute; left:0; height:81px}
#slider img {cursor:pointer; border:1px solid #666; padding:2px}
```

I'm viewing this website on an iMac but it's also off center when using Firefox on Windows so is there anything I can reformat in the CSS sheet to work cross browser?

Thanks in advanced.
Luke

Comment: Is this live somewhere I can take a look at?

Comment: Only CSS is not enough. Post HTML as well and create a jsfiddle.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache on Chrome? It can get a little 'sticky' sometimes. It would be worth checking via the inspector ([cmd]+[alt]+[i]) that the css being loaded matches what you think it should be loading.

Comment: Due to Apple's restriction, Chrome on iDevices is actually Safari Mobile (possibly with some feature disabled). It would be nice if you can provide a link or better a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so people can checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use a [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) stylesheet to make browsers see it the same way.

Link to that stylesheet before linking to your own stylesheet, this might make somes changes, but then you can work around playing with it, and then it should look the same in all the browsers.

Also a good trick is to check if the browser supports the css which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your responses.
I would post the live link but it's not live yet only on local.

I have however fixed the problem.

For anyone seeing this and needs help it's this line here:

```
#image img {position:absolute; z-index:25; width:auto}
```

Adding in **left:0; top:0;** to the line told the img to line up to the corner of the parent div

So the line is now

```
#image img {position:absolute; left:0; top:0; z-index:25; width:auto}
```

Thank you again everyone.